# MQPUT is successful but message not available in remote queue

Tags: ibm-mq

MQPUT returns a successful post response (00) on IBM ZOS IMS online service, but the message is not getting inserted into the Remote queue. The queue connection was successful as well.

Program is written in cobol with IMS interface and the module is invoked through the IMS Websphere bridge interface.

Comment: Hello there - could you add your MQPUT code to the question so we can help further? Also, could you explain exactly what you are checking for zero. You say "post response" and I want to be sure what you mean. The CompCode parameter (2nd last on MQPUT) is an output parameter and that is where you should be checking for zero (or not zero). Is this what you mean? If CompCode is non-zero then the Reason parameter (last on MQPUT) will have a number in the 2000+ range (decimal) which explains more.

Comment: Its a simple code which involves the call to MQPUT using the queue name as the object descriptor, the connection identifier and the MQPUT module returns the response as zeros .. There is one other weird scenario is that the same module when it is invoked in the batch process it is able to post the message to the queue which is kind of perplexing to me.

Comment: @DinishBS without the code (and MQ setup) it is impossible to tell you where the issue is. If you don't post the code, we cannot help you, we can only guess.

Comment: @DinishBS again the way you describe how you check the return code, "module returns the response as zeros" makes me think you are not checking the value in the CompCode output parameter (2nd last parameter on MQPUT) and are instead checking the module return code. Please confirm. Posting your code and most specifically how you find the zero return code would help us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

By default for MQ on z/OS, MQPUTs are done under a local UOW.  i.e. MQPMO-SYNCPOINT is set for Put Message Options.  Hence, the code must perform an MQCMIT API call.

Update the code to use MQPMO-NO-SYNCPOINT and then the message will not be held waiting for an MQCMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, actually, the program had a rollback on the Logical unit of work when the program faces a failure situation, so in this case the program updated to the MQ but the roll back happened at the end of the processing ...